# Substitutions in like statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, query-optimization, sql-like

I have a `synonyms table` called syns to store the word and the existing synonyms. In the same fashion, there is another table called subs that contains `word substitutions` for a word. Those tables are used to find similar values in a master table called `institutions` which hosts the existing names in the database.

The purpose of this is to avoid names which are similar considering synonyms and word substitution. The user provides a new institution name and before inserting into institution table, there are several queries replacing each word by its both synonyms and word substitutions. For instance, I have the following data:

```
substitution word table:
WORD      SUBS_LIST
MOUNTAIN  MOUNTAIN, MOUNT, MT, MTN
VIEW      VIEW, VU
FORMULA   FORMULA, 4MULA
```

```
Synonym list table:
WORD    SYN_LIST
EDUCATION   SCHOOL, UNIVERSITY, COLLEGE, TRAINING
```

```
institutions table:
NAME
FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY
FOURMULAE VULCAN COLLEGE
4MULA VU CAFE
```

The institution table contains all the existing names in the database. Then, when receiving a new name, this does not have to be similar when replacing each word with its respective synonym list and word substitution. For instance, a new name such as `FORMULA VU SCHOOL` should be found as existing in database due to existing record `FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY`.

I created [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ae989cf40f9484031ea03301a3f9b8f3) to show this idea. However, I am not getting any results on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below function seems to be working. It uses one of the split comma-separated strings into words technique, you can apply other. But the best thing would be changing data model to single word-synonym, this way you could avoid splitting, which may be not reliable. You can use this function when you check new entry, something like:

```
where replace_synonyms(inserted_value) <> replace_synonyms(existing_value)
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=54bcb80c136ff3b9fb03a660f79bf60b)</sup>**

Test:

```
select replace_synonyms('FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY') from dual;  
-- FORMULA VIEW EDUCATION
select replace_synonyms('CANTINA TRAINING MT')     from dual;  
-- FOOD EDUCATION MOUNTAIN
```

Function:

```
create or replace function replace_synonyms(i_text in varchar2) return varchar2
is
    p_text varchar2(4000) := i_text;

    cursor c_subs is
    select word, trim(column_value) text 
      from subs, xmltable(('"' ||replace(subs_list, ',', '","') || '"'))
      where p_text like '%'||trim(column_value)||'%'
    union 
    select word, trim(column_value) text 
      from syns, xmltable(('"' ||replace(syn_list, ',', '","') || '"'))
      where p_text like '%'||trim(column_value)||'%';

begin
   for i in c_subs
    loop
      p_text := regexp_replace(
          p_text, '(^|[^a-z0-9])' || i.text || '($|[^a-z0-9])', 
          '\1' || i.word || '\2', 1, 0,  'i');
    end loop;

   return p_text;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ponder Stibbons, it is a beautiful solution. Just a question, how about when the word appears in two categories? I have been thinking during the day, but I haven't been able to come up with an idea to get several records based on the number of categories a word is in. For a more specific example, please take a look at this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c83b02367701392c527693f442479798

Comment: I tried to store the possible values in an array when a word matches several categories, but I got `ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit, but I increased the size of the array. Please check this latest version trying to have a working version to deal with words with matches in several categories: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1b5a2e3508a3508decfb4f6a49b715c3

Comment: it seems I have the dbfiddle working as PL/SQL block, but I am getting an error when transforming it into function. I am getting the error: `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error` on line 37: `array(1):= p_text;`. In the PL/SQL block, I got the correct records, but now I am getting that error. Do you have any idea how can I fix it? Do you think it is a good approach the one I used to find a word with several matches in different categories in synonym list? Thanks a lot

Comment: About this error I tried to replicate it in simplified example and found nothing. You have to debug values and see what is converted. But I would not store same values as `WORD` and part of `SYN_LIST`. This is straight way to infinite loop.

Comment: Do you think storing in an array is the way ehen I have words with several synonyms?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm my understanding
The first part of the search string "FORMULA VU SCHOOL" is "FORMULA" which needs to be checked in the table institutions if there is a string that begins with "FORMULA".
In this case there is a hit "FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY"

Then take the second portion of the string("VIEW") and look it up the table subs.

Then take the third portion of the string("UNIVERSITY") and look it up the table syns

After that the found string in the table Institutions would be translated as

FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY = FORMULA VIEW EDUCATION

Since we are searching to see if "FORMULA VU SCHOOL" already exists, when translating in the fashion above we would get

FORMULA VU SCHOOL = FORMULA VIEW EDUCATION

And since such a translated record already exists in the table Institution, that record needs to be shown up as follows in the expected output

```
Existing_column_value   search_string_value
FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY FORMULA VU SCHOOL
```

can you confirm if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: It is a bit different. To be clearer, let's change the example a little bit. Assume we have `4MULA VU SCHOOL`. Each word needs to check for word substitution and synonym. For instance, the first word `4MULA`, just have word substitution then it is changed to FORMULA, then the second word `VU`, also just have word substitution, then it is replaced by  `VIEW`.  Last word `SCHOOL` is checked by word substitution, but it does not have, then we check synonym list and 'SCHOOL` is found in the same list as 'UNIVERSITY'. As result, `4MULA VU SCHOOL` is considered the same as `FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY`